# grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into/ target on installation from 16.04.4 live usb on Dell Inspiron 3180

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, touchpad

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop (Dell Inspiron 3180). I tried a live 18.04 USB first of all but it kept freezing after a few seconds, keypad or touch pad wouldn't work both when trying the installer and running live. Windows 10 was pre installed on the laptop

I made a 16.04.4 USB, when I tried this live, the touchpad wouldn't work, but I was able to navigate and use the keypad. I figured if I could complete the installation it would free up the USB slot for me to try a wired mouse which might work. I began the installation and everything worked until I received the error:

> 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into/ target/. without the grub boot loader....

I couldn't read the rest as the installation was trying to move on and the screen faded and powered down. When I restarted the PC it was running a hardware diagnostic.

Any ideas on what to try would be appreciated?

[Here are some photos](https://we.tl/9zS73Zs5tO) showing how I tried the installation step by step

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81132/discussion-on-question-by-d-draw-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install).

Answer (score -1):

How's it going, I have tried every series of ubuntu 18,16,14, budgie, bodhi, lubtuntu. The only one that I could get to work right out of installation was ubuntu 14.04. Every time I upgrade it freezes etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your response doesn't explain why other versions of Ubuntu didn't work (if your equipment is the same as the poster's), but try to avoid recommending end-of-life versions.  Additionally, your post does not address the potential causes of this problem for the poster - such as EFI/UEFI versus BIOS installations.  "Me too" style response don't help posters fix the problem(s) that they have identified.

Comment: Well, clayton, it does explain what i did, i tried those versions. And it froze. Freezing means i cannot look at anything. Frozen, not like the movie. In frozen i mean that when i start the computer nothing happens. So, my answer is 14.04 ubuntu loaded and installed. The others qould not boot into installation meaning it froze "couldnt do anything" as soon as it popped up. Your response is "not explaining" anything, my response explained that every other version "end" froze other than 14.04 "end.

Comment: Also, if you didnt see the comment above. This was sent to "chat" (: